# Conditional directory info on VB

Tags: vb.net, directoryinfo

I'm looking for the folders information with the method :
 `Dim Drs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()`

But I want only to save on this array the folders that contain "CP" on the beginning of the name .

How do I work this out?

Best Regards 
A

Comment: Consider using a search pattern, GetDirectories("CP*")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
Dim directoryQuery = From dir In di.EnumerateDirectories()
                     Where dir.Name.StartsWith("CP")
Dim Drs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = directoryQuery.ToArray()
```

Comment: Haha, beat me to it. However, I'm glad you did, your answer is far more concise, nice.